# What are the orange rings, and what happens when you collect/smash them?

Tags: onrush

I've noticed a lot of these orange donut things around the tracks during games.  They never seem to be in the same places, nor are they ever shown in blue, only orange.  They feel almost like tombstones in that they're static icons that can be "collected" by driving over them with your vehicle.

What do they do, and what causes them?

[image: Image credit: IGN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, when you collect these, it even pops up "+Tombstone" at the bottom.

These are tombstones from fodder vehicles.  You can see them appear when fodder gets crushed around you.  As with other tombstones, collecting a fodder tombstone will award you a small amount of boost.